# Authentication error occurred in RavenDB Studio

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I have installed and configured RavenDB in one of the server environment. (Windows 2012) I need to secure the Ravendb Studio, hence created self-signed certificate and applied the changed in the settings.json as given below

```
{
"ServerUrl": "https://11.135.25.16:12345",
"Setup.Mode": "None",
"Security.UnsecuredAccessAllowed":"PrivateNetwork",
"License.Eula.Accepted": true,
"Security.Certificate": {
    "Path": "cloud16_company_com.pfx",
    "Password": "123456789"
},
}
```

Once RavenDB starts it seems good and it is running on the given URL. But when I browse using Internet Explorer or chrome, it says "Authentication Error occurred". 
[image: Error]

Thanks

Comment: Additional information I am using development license.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you didn't register a client certificate to use for authentication.
You can register `cloud16_company_com.pfx` as the client certificate, which will work because RavenDB trust its own certificate. Or you can register an explicit client certificate.
That is probably a better idea. See here how to register / generate your client certificate:

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/csharp/server/security/authentication/client-certificate-usage

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Still I am facing a different error now. I tried installing using Raven wizard using Let's encrypt. I configured with 3 nodes, it get succeeded including domain registration after that it asked me to restart. I clicked restart, but server is unavailable. URL I registered is https://srghome.ravendb.community  I want to know does it requires real domain ? Please let me know what went wrong.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken from: [RavenDB Documentation](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/csharp/server/security/common-errors-and-faq#authentication-issues)

- Try closing all instances of the browser and then restart it.
- If that doesn't work, register the client certificate in the OS store.
   
  In Windows, double-click the certificate file and click 'next' all the way.